# Alternative Servlet if initialization stage fails

Tags: servlets, exception

During loading or initializing stage of a Servet, if due to some unknown reason, exception is thrown,do we have way to call some alternative Servlet ( may be some callback mechanism ? ).

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing about that in Jee specs. The init method should use (ie throw) an UnavailableException to indicate a permanent or temporary failure...but what that means is definitely up to the container which can be different between vendors.

However, even in "vendor" extensions (e.g. websphere, jboss, weblogic) I never seen a feature like that